# str_to_date returns null in query but fine on its own

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to sort some results by time. I've gathered str_to_date is the way to go, but I appear to be using it wrong, and I can't tell for sure, but I think it's converting to NULL and then not sorting in a meaningful way:

```
mysql> SELECT member_id, result_result, str_to_date('result_result','%i:%s.%f') FROM results WHERE workout_id = '2' ORDER BY str_to_date('result_result','%i:%s.%f') LIMIT 5;
+-----------+---------------+-----------------------------------------+
| member_id | result_result | str_to_date('result_result','%i:%s.%f') |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------------------------------+
|         0 | 1:35.0        | NULL                                    |
|         1 | 1:35.0        | NULL                                    |
|         3 | 1:40          | NULL                                    |
|         4 | 1:37.8        | NULL                                    |
|         7 | 1:27.3        | NULL                                    |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------------------------------+
5 rows in set, 5 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

but the two result types seem to convert fine if I do it manually:

```
mysql> select str_to_date('1:40','%i:%s.%f');
+--------------------------------+
| str_to_date('1:40','%i:%s.%f') |
+--------------------------------+
| 00:01:40                       |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select str_to_date('1:35.0','%i:%s.%f');
+----------------------------------+
| str_to_date('1:35.0','%i:%s.%f') |
+----------------------------------+
| 00:01:35                         |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any ideas what's happening / how to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the quotes inside the function. Try

```
str_to_date( result_result, '%i:%s.%f' )
```